# Design Time Lookup in MuleStudio from WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: registry, repository, wso2, mule, wso2-esb

I am trying to WSO2 G-Reg with MuleESB. 
As part of design time lookup I want to look for SOA assets and register SOA assets from MuleStudio.
Can someone suggest a feasible approach to achieve this.

Thanks,
Wajid